# Pairwise Wasserstein distance on 2 arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, distance

I try to compare sports formations and therefore need to compare how similar distributions of points (x, y) coordinates are to eventually cluster them. I am working with a 3D array of the following form:

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as distance
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]],
                 [[5, 6], [7, 8], [5, 6], [7, 8], [5, 6], [7, 8], [5, 6], [7, 8], [5, 6], [7, 8]]])
```

I have implemented the following custom metric for the wasserstein distance (the l and k is just for different scaling of the data to compare formations of varying density):

```
def wasserstein_distance_function(f1, f2):
    min_cost = np.inf
    f1 = f1.reshape((10, 2))
    f2 = f2.reshape((10, 2))
    for l in np.linspace(0.8, 1.2, 3):
        for k in np.linspace(0.8, 1.2, 3):
            cost = distance.cdist(l * f1, k * f2, 'sqeuclidean')
            row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(cost)
            curr_cost = cost[row_ind, col_ind].sum()
            if curr_cost < min_cost:
                min_cost = curr_cost
    return min_cost
```

My question is: how to I implement the pairwise comparison via sklearn, so far I got to:

```
def pairwise_wasserstein(points):
    """
    Helper function to perform the pairwise distance function of all points within 'points' parameter

    """
    # return pairwise_distances(points, metric=wasserstein_distance_function)
    # print(points)
    return pairwise_distances(points, metric=wasserstein_distance_function)
```

which throws me either a

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

or an

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. check_pairwise_arrays expected <= 2.
```

error. I understand that it has to do with my data being a 3D np array, but for simple comparisons, f.ex.

```
wasserstein_distance_function(data[0], data[1])
```

returns a valid value. Any clues on how to get it to work for an array for maybe 1000 formations to find pairwise distances that I can feed into an AgglomerativeClustering algorithm? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what are the shapes of `data[0]`?  it looks like `wasserstein_distance_function` requires that f1 and f2 contain 20 elements each which it interprets as that as 10 points in 2d - is that right?

Comment: That is correct. More specifically, the data represents x and y coordinates of soccer players (10 in-field players) of which I'd like to compare the formations and how similar formations are. I am using the Wasserstein metric as a means to compare the similarity across formation observations.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `wasserstein_distance_function()` requires the input to be 2D, but `pairwise_wasserstein()` requires 2D input as well. And since `pairwise_wasserstein()` splits your input to compute it pairwise, it will split the 2D data into 1-dimensional data, which won't work with your `wasserstein_distance_function()` anymore. And when you provide 3D data to the `pairwise_wasserstein()`, it throws an error because it can't work with that.

I would suggest to just write your own helper method, which iterates through all your data points pairwise, and computes the wasserstein distance for you.

**Suggestion for a possible solution:**

```
def pairwise_wasserstein(points):
    """
    Helper function to perform the pairwise distance function of all points within 'points' parameter
    """
    for first_index in range(0,points.shape[0]):
      for second_index in range(first_index+1,points.shape[0]):
        print("First index: ", first_index, ", Second index: ", second_index, ", Distance: ",wasserstein_distance_function(points[first_index],points[second_index]))
```

**Example input with 4 data points:**

```
data = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]],
                 [[5, 6], [7, 8], [5, 6], [7, 8], [5, 6], [7, 8], [5, 6], [7, 8], [5, 6], [7, 8]],
                 [[1, 15], [3, 2], [1, 2], [5, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]],
                 [[5, 1], [7, 8], [5, 6], [7, 1], [5, 6], [7, 8], [5, 1], [7, 8], [5, 6], [7, 8]]])
```

**Example output:**

```
First index:  0 , Second index:  1 , Distance:  100.80000000000005
First index:  0 , Second index:  2 , Distance:  76.4
First index:  0 , Second index:  3 , Distance:  96.32000000000002
First index:  1 , Second index:  2 , Distance:  215.00000000000003
First index:  1 , Second index:  3 , Distance:  55.68000000000002
First index:  2 , Second index:  3 , Distance:  186.88
```

Comment: perfect, that makes a lot more sense! any idea on how to return a distance_matrix from this pairwise function to feed into the fcluster() method of scipy.cluster.hierarchy?

Thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: No, sorry. I am not familiar with the scipy.cluster.hierarchy module. You can ask a new question regarding that though and somebody else might be able to help you with it then.